# Como efectuar Estorno de documentos de liquidação

Tags: vba

Eu tenho um desenvolvimento em dotnet que consiste num integrador de documentos de outro sistema em Primavera V9 e pretendo efectuar o estorno de documentos de liquidação (REC) para o respectivo documento de Estorno (DEV).

O DEV é um novo documento de liquidação que está configurado como documento de estorno dos REC.

Saliento o facto de os documentos terem integração on-line na contabilidade e respectiva ligação à tesouraria.

**Exemplo do que estou a executar mas em VBA (funcionando desta forma depois será transportar para o projecto DotNet):**

```
Public Sub testeEstorno()

Dim DocEstorno As New GcpBEDocumentoLiq
Dim docliq As New GcpBEDocumentoLiq

DocEstorno.Tipodoc = "DEV"
DocEstorno.Serie = "2019"
DocEstorno.DataIntroducao = CDate("01/07/2019")
DocEstorno.DataDoc = CDate("01/07/2019")
DocEstorno.TipoEntidade = "C"
DocEstorno.Entidade = "00055879"

DocEstorno.ValorRec = docliq.ValorRec
DocEstorno.docliq = docliq.id

BSO.Comercial.Liquidacoes.PreencheDadosRelacionados DocEstorno

'ID do REC
Set docliq = BSO.Comercial.Liquidacoes.EditaID("1128DD3F-8D2D-11E9-A3A9-DC4A3EECC8FC")


BSO.Comercial.Liquidacoes.EstornaDocumentoLiquidacao docliq.id, DocEstorno, "005"
BSO.Comercial.Liquidacoes.Actualiza DocEstorno
End Sub
```

**Obtém-se erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para estornar um documento de liquidação por motores Primavera, precisas de usar o método *PreencheDadosDocumentoEstorno* em vez do *PreencheDadosRelacionados*. 
O metodo *PreencheDadosDocumentoEstorno*  precisa de receber o Id do documento que vais estornar, tipo de documento de estorno, serie e o motivo de estorno.

Segue um exemplo simples  em que estou a estornar um RE com um ERE:

```
Dim DocEstorno As New GcpBEDocumentoLiq

Set DocEstorno = BSO.Comercial.Liquidacoes.PreencheDadosDocumentoEstorno("B7EC09A2-5A04-11E9-B6A7-94C6912FA392", "ERE", "2019", "005", "teste")

BSO.Comercial.Liquidacoes.EstornaDocumentoLiquidacao "B7EC09A2-5A04-11E9-B6A7-94C6912FA392", DocEstorno, "005"
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada colega, funcionou na perfeição.Bom trabalho.